# Mistake on s0 register while printing

Tags: assembly, mips

There is unusual behavior in my code that I just can't figure out

```
        .data
hello:      .asciiz "Hello\n"
msg1:       .asciiz "lol"
msg2:       .asciiz "msg2"
        .text
main:
    la $a0, hello
    jal print

la $a0, msg1
jal create
move $s1, $v0 #s0

move $a0, $v0
jal print

la $a0, msg2
jal create
move $s2, $v0 #s1

move $a0, $v0
jal print

move $a0, $s1 #s0
move $a1, $s2 #s1
jal append

move $a0, $v0
jal print

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

In the line where is a comment, if i switch s1 with s0 and s2 with s1, my code don't work the way it shold. Whatever other index for save registers I use, code behave is good, but if I use 0, program make a mistake.

Comment: 'My program make a mistake' is not a problem description.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077852/mips-is-it-elegant-to-use-s0-etc-reginsters-inside-the-procedure-and-restore for why you shouldn't be modifying S0 or any S register.

It's a matter of luck using S1 or S2 isn't an issue.

Comment: The code you've shown us is not sufficient to reproduce the problem since you haven't included any of the subroutines that you're calling (`create`, `print`, `append`).

Comment: Michael is correct. Edit your post to include the missing subroutines. They are what is causing the issue. There's no clue in the posted code. BTW, you are correct regarding the use of the `s*` regs. In a small program, you needn't follow the ABI. And, setting `s*` in `main` _is_ ABI conforming, anyway. If you're only calling routines that _you_ create you can use any reg for any purpose.

Answer (score 1):

These are the 32 MIPS registers and what they do.

```
        $zero 0 constant value 0 
        $at 1 assembler temp 
        $v0 2 funcZon return  
        $v1 3 funcZon return 
        $a0 4 argument 
        $a1 5 argument 
        $a2 6 argument 
        $a3 7 argument 
        $t0 8 temporary value 
        $t1 9 temporary value 
        $t2 10 temporary value 
        $t3 11 temporary value 
        $t4 12 temporary value 
        $t5 13 temporary value 
        $t6 14 temporary value 
        $t7 15 temporary value 
        $s0 16 saved temporary 
        $s1 17 saved temporary 
        $s2 18 saved temporary 
        $s3 19 saved temporary 
        $s4 20 saved temporary 
        $s5 21 saved temporary 
        $s6 22 saved temporary 
        $s7 23 saved temporary 
        $t8 24 temporary value 
        $t9 25 temporary value 
        $k0 26 reserved for OS 
        $k1 27 reserved for OS 
        $gp 28 global pointer 
        $sp 29 stack pointer 
        $fp 30 frame pointer 
        $ra 31 return address
```

The difference between `$s` and `$t` registers are that `$s` registers are the same after a function return while there is no guarantee for this for the `$t` registers.

If you use the `$s` registers you must save and restore their values. For example, if function `create` uses registers `$t0` and `$s0` and then calls a function `print`, it must save the register `$t0` if it wants to use it after `print` returns. `print` must save `$s0` before it can begin using it.

In this case, it looks like you should use a `$t` register.

Comment: Because of `s` registers saves there content, that was a reason i used them. For `print`, i used register $t0, so I didn't want to use it because my data will be overwritten. For any other $s register, whatever index i use except 0, it work correctly

Comment: Unlike most arches, mips doesn't hardwire registers. The H/W hardwires `$zero` to the value 0. The `jal` instruction hardwires to `$ra`, but `jalr` does _not_. There are no `push/pop` insts, so the stack pointer can be any reg [if you need one at all]. In a self contained program, you can use any register for any purpose. The ABI is much more of just a "suggestion" (i.e. invent your own conventions). OP's use of `s*` is perfectly fine [and _is_ ABI conforming here]--The caller of `main` doesn't set `s*`, so `main` can set them without saving.

Comment: Look, I appreciate your help a lot, and I learned something from your last comment but, in my example, $v0 which I was moving was only an integer value of some small number like 13 or so. That is why it wasn't clear to me what problem was happening cause even `$s0` register haven't been used in any other function i think. 
Thanks anyway and if you have time for one more question, how can i print the result of multiplication stored in 2 registers (hi and lo). They are in two different registers...